# What is a CBV mixin in Django?

Tags: python, django, mixins

I was reading about the Django `UserPassesTestMixin`mixin, and I came across the term `CBV Mixin`. What is this, and how is it useful? Is a `CBV` Mixin a general type of mixins, and are there `CBV` mixins in any other framework apart from Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CBV, in Django, stands for "class based views". These are a set of views provided by the framework as Python classes rather than functions. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/) for a fuller explanation.

They're implemented in part by composing mixin classes defining specific behaviors with base classes such as the `View` base class. Again, the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins/) have additional details about the standard/included mixins. For example, the common behavior of rendering a template to produce a response is defined in [TemplateResponseMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin).

Answer (score 0):

`CBV` is just a shortcut from Class-based views, which is a generic term for any view in Django that is defined as a class in your code, especially one inheriting from `django.views.View`.

So the `CBV Mixin` is just any mixin that can be used in a Class-based view.

Answer (score 0):

`CBV` or `Class Based Views` and are predefined classes from `django.views.generic` developed for specific tasks like `ListView`, `CreateView`, and so on.
`CBV Mixins` are just like normal `CBV` but they are designed to add some restrictions to the `CBV` like `LoginRequiredMixin` and `UserPassesTestMixin`, for more details refer to this links:
1- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/
2- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/mixins/
3- https://djangodeconstructed.com/2020/04/27/roll-your-own-class-based-views-in-django/